# Installing Fedora from USB key

Tags: fedora, boot, usb, system-installation

How do I load a Fedora DVD iso onto USB so I can install it from there.
I've tried `dd` as in here: [Fedora instructions](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Installation_Guide/Making_USB_Media-UNIX_Linux.html) but for some reason this didn't work.

Here's what I've tried:

```
sudo dd if=Fedora-15-x86_64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdb1
```

and

```
sudo dd if=Fedora-15-x86_64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

The USB key contains DVD information - I've looked it up, but the laptop simply skips the USB key and boots from harddrive. I've obviously configured BIOS to boot from USB first and I also tried selecting USB key from <kbd>F12</kbd> menu.

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone tried installing from USB key using `dd` before?

Comment: `dd`ing the `netinst` ISO to a USB drive should work fine.  Have you tried using a different USB key or trying it in a different computer to eliminate hardware problems from the equation?  (USB boot is quite finicky; it took me four tries to get a Windows 7 install from USB to work yesterday!)  Alternatively, you could try the [boot.fp.o](http://boot.fedoraproject.org/) images or [installing from a hard drive partition](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Installation_Guide/s1-steps-hd-installs-x86.html) instead.

Comment: I've tried DVD and netinstall iso on 2 different flash drives with no result. Live cds worked fine on usb drive, but I wanted minimal installation and live cds don't allow you to customize package selection durion the install. I ended up simply burning the image. Not sure if it was my laptop or what else.

Comment: Not all iso images are compatibles with usb drives. You need a iso with a especial hybrid format, not the traditional. This requires extra work from the developers, doesn't exist a magic tool. Maybe the netinstall iso doesn't compatible with usb sticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second command is the correct. Try this:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb*
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
sudo sync
sudo dd if=Fedora-15-x86_64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdb
sudo sync
```

If you have the same errors, try the GNOME or KDE livecd in your USB stick. If all fail, the problem is your hardware.

Comment: thanks. It's probably my laptop, I've ended up burning the image and installing from cd. Good to know that this should work since someone on fedora irc channel told me that only live images can be dd'ed, and not DVD or netinstall.

Answer (score 2):

There is loads of useful information on http://www.pendrivelinux.com/category/usb-installs-from-linux/

Ubuntu comes with a utility called [Startup disk creator](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)
which you could use from a live ubuntu CD.

I always use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) though as you can play about with the settings a bit more and make live USB with persistent storage and carry your desktop in your pocket.

Comment: ubuntu's now only works with ubuntu (at least for me) :/, and `unetbootin` doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have had great luck with [this Windows app](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create a bootable USB. I ran the live version of Fedora 15 from it just last week on one of my laptops.